# "Other" one-sided inverses

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

If a matrix has linearly independent columns, then if it's a **square** matrix it has linearly independent rows.  Forget square matrices; think of this:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix} \bullet & \bullet \\ \bullet & \bullet \\ \bullet & \bullet \\ \bullet & \bullet \\ \bullet & \bullet \\ \bullet & \bullet \\ \bullet & \bullet \\ \end{bmatrix}
$$

The matrix has a **left** inverse if and only if its columns are linearly independent.  The most usually seen left inverse is the Moore–Penrose pseudo-inverse
$$
B=(A^TA)^{-1} A^T.
$$
This left inverse $B$ enjoys the properties that

- $BA$ is a small identity matrix (with just as many rows or columns as $A$ has columns); and
- The large singular matrix $AB$ is that of the orthogonal projection onto the column space of $A$, i.e. $ABx = $ projection  of $x$ onto that space.

But there are infinitely many other left inverses of this matrix.  These also satisfy the first of the two bulleted points above, but (I think?) they don't satisfy the second.

**Are those other one-sided inverses of interest for some reason?  Do they have any nice properties?  Can things of interest be said about them?**

Comment: See here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse

Comment: @vadim123 : Is my question answered in that Wikipedia article?

Comment: Well, it refers to [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drazin_inverse) and [that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse).